# accessing port 8443 with http in tomcat

Tags: http, tomcat, ssl, https

I have a Tomcat 6.x or 7.x web application server running on a webserver listening on port 8443.

Why is it that when I access http://:8443, I am 
prompted to download a file of the format application/octet-stream from any browser from any platform?

When I access http://:443 I get a 400 Bad Request.

Is there anyway to configure Tomcat to yield a 400 Bad Request error code if a user attempts to access the SSL port via http ?

Comment: Very confused. Which version of Tomcat?? Your URLs look broken. Is that to indicate that you have a hostname but you don't want to publish it? Fine, but use something like `myhost`. You should post your Tomcat `<Connector>` configurations. When you "access" `:443` and `:8443` what request are you sending?

Answer (score 3):

It's because you need to type https:// beforehand :D I just had the same problem! 
I think some forwarding is needed to ensure https is used.