# http request + port 8443

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, https

My question is quite similar like this ([accessing port 8443 with http in tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152498/accessing-port-8443-with-http-in-tomcat)), however the question was not answered.

I am developing a site and I am using Eclipse Juno and Tomcat 7.
I have configured tomcat to accept https request.

```xml
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" 
           clientAuth="false" 
           keystoreFile="C:\ssl\.keystore" 
           keystorePass="changeit" 
           maxThreads="150" 
           port="8443" 
           protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           scheme="https" 
           secure="true" 
           sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

So, when you access the site through https + 8443, it presents a warning message, therefore it was successfully configured.

Also, I redirected all http request to https by adding this code to my web.xml:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HTTPSOnly</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HTTPSOrHTTP</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.ico</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/img/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

So, when you access the site using http + 8080, you are redirected to https + 8443.

However, one problem that I encounter is when the user use http + 8443.
So, when you access the URL, it prompts a download dialog.

Is there any way to throw an error message or a redirection perhaps when you access the site using http + 8443?

Comment: Is it a file download dialog or a dialog that warns that the SSL certificate is self signed?

Comment: It is a file download. the warning message appears when you use https + 8443 which means that the ssl is working.